# fade in element showing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im using jquery to fade in a hamburger menu on scroll, but for some reason it is showing on load, then when you scroll it fades out and back in again. Once you scroll down and back up it behaves correctly its just the issue with it showing on initial page load. How can I stop it showing on load?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
        $('#menuhamburger').fadeIn();
       } else {
        $('#menuhamburger').fadeOut();
       }
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *scroll* listener is after the *ready* event is complete so that means that first the page will load and then you'll monitor for scrolling.

So if you want the initially the hamburger menu to be hidden you'll either have to have a initial hidden state

```css
#menuhamburger{
    display:none;
}
```

or you'll have to also execute your logic directly after `$(document).ready()`

here follows an example of the first variant, where the element #menuhamburger is initially hidden

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
        $('#menuhamburger').fadeIn();
       } else {
        $('#menuhamburger').fadeOut();
       }
      });
});
```

```css
#container{
  height:10000px;
}

#menuhamburger{
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


<div id="menuhamburger">
  Menu
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would you also know how to add a media query to that, so that fade is disabled below 769px?

Comment: @gjjr you can have an early return in your scroll handler that would look like this `if ($(this).width() < 769){return}`  but depending on your use case you may require a CSS media query too (if you would want the menu hamburger to be displayed on screens < 769px)

Comment: would it not be "window" insteadof "(this)"?

Comment: this and window in this context would be the same because it is the handler of `$(window).scroll`

Comment: but you could totally use window instead if you want

Comment: So I updated the code and its half working, the issue now is that if you resize the browser without scrolling, the menu doesnt show up at all, but if you scroll first to show the menu and then resize it shows and doesnt fade as intended. 

Ive edited your code above to show.

Comment: that is why you'll have to have a CSS media query to remove the `display:none;` attribute

Comment: so in the end you can add to your CSS that would look something like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #menuhamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}`

Comment: I already have CSS in place for that, but wouldnt it be min width not max width? `@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
#menuhamburger {
    display: none;
}`

so that it doesnt display above 769 until the js fadein is applied...but should show all the time below 769 (which is currently doesnt)

Comment: ok I think I got what is your issue. Basically because you are resizing the screen, the previous logic is still applied (it is different than loading the website in smaller screens). To fix that you'll have to handle the resize event. I have created a demo for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/5fLhswra/1/

Comment: ahh that makes sense, ok that has made the menu appear below 769px, but it has disappeared completely above 769

Comment: it disappears when above 769 but when you scroll down it appears (wasn't that the required functionality?)

Comment: Ignore that, fixed the issue and its working now, thanks!